# How can I select first letter of text wrote as a tag and change it css?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the color first letter only (B O L D) of the code when I hover .tab

```
 <ul class="tab">
                <li><a href="#base">BASE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#other1">OTHER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#label">LABEL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#direct">DIRECT</a></li>
            </ul>
```

and I use this jQuery

```
var words = $('.tab > li > a').text().split('1');
  $('.tab').hover(function(){
   words.css("color","#3f9cd6");
});
```

but the color is not changed. How can I fix this jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a CSS only method using `::first-letter` [CSS pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

**Example**

```css
.tab li:hover::first-letter {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#base">BASE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#other1">OTHER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#label">LABEL</a></li>
  <li><a href="#direct">DIRECT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is about a million times better than my answer 